# Tmux send-keys stripping space

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to run a series of commands in tmux from a remote file like so:

```
tmux $(wget -qO- http://example.com/tmux)
```

The file contains commands like `split-window` and `send-keys`

The problem is, `send-keys` is stripping spaces. The send-keys commands is:

```
send-keys ssh example.com C-m;
```

But instead it sends `sshexample.com`

Any idea why?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess, it's interpreting "`send-keys ssh example.com C-m;`" as four separate arguments and not knowing what to put between them.

Try:

```
tmux "$(wget -qO- http://example.com/tmux)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not that send-keys is "stripping spaces" exactly, but that Space is one of the special keys recognized by tmux and expected to be used with the `send-keys` command.

So, rather than

`send-keys ssh example.com C-m;`

in this case, you would use

`send-keys ssh Space example.com C-m;`

More on this can be found on [tmux send-keys syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19330452/1668057)

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because the `<Space>` key is considered a special character. To fix the issue, you need to escape the character by using the `\` key.

Let's say we want to send the command `ipython --no-autoindent` to the terminal. If we did it like this:

`tmux send-keys 'ipython --no-autoindent`

The output sent would be:
`$ ipython--no-autoindent`

==================================

This is how to send it with escaping the space:

`tmux send-keys 'ipython \ --no-autoindent'`

And if you try it, your output would be: `$ ipython --no-autoindent`

Answer (score -1):

I've struggled a bit with similar issue. The solution turned out to be:

```
tmux send-keys -l $var;
tmux send-keys C-m;
```

thanks to `-l`, tmux paid attention to all the signs. On the downside, it didn't accept `<enter>` so separated call is required.